# How to fix my Applescript plugins for the Contacts application that are no longer available since 10.9 Mavericks upgrade?

Tags: macos, applescript, contacts, plugins

I have got 5 scripts listed in `~/Library/Address Book Plug-Ins/`

1. SkypeABDialer.bundle
2. SkypeABSMS.bundle
3. TelephoneAddressBookPhonePlugIn.bundle
4. TelephoneAddressBookSIPAddressPlugIn.bundle
5. Dial with Snom VoIP phone.scpt

Since the OS upgrade from 10.7 (Lion) to 10.9 (Mavericks) the .bundle plug-ins are still available within the "Contacts" application, however the AppleScript (.scpt) version is no longer listed at the former entry points.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. The launch services database is screwed up

This Contacts.app launch services problem/issue might appear again after each Mac OS X update, like the 10.9.2 combo updater according to http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/2NbVio0gzU3nWMhAxfsk

#### 1a. Command line fix

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -all l,s,u
```

In case of error messages like `no such file or directory` you can find the location of your `lsregister` with the command `$ locate lsregister`.

#### 1b. OnyX fix

Or, you can run the [OnyX application](http://www.titanium.free.fr/downloadonyx.php) (version 2.8.7),
go to tab "**Automation**".

Disable each check mark,
except for section "**Rebuilding**",
and make sure that item "**LaunchServices**" is checked.

Finally hit the [ Execute ] button.

### 2. Move to new folder

You need to move your Address Book Plug-In AppleScript(s) from the old

```
~/Library/Address Book Plug-Ins/
/Library/Address Book Plug-Ins/
```

to a new location:

```
~/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.AddressBook/
```